# Ubuntu 18.04 SR-IOV on Intel ixgbe - Intel X550

Tags: networking, virtualization

I'm having issues on creating VF with ubuntu 18.04.
SR-IOV is enabled from BIOS, the NIC are Intel X550, I added 
`intel_iommu=on` to `/etc/default/grub` and also tried using modprobe.d
by adding `options ixgbe max_vfs=8` on `/etc/modprobe.d/ixgbe.conf`

But if I check using `lspci | grep -i ethernet` I only get the physical cards.
I have also tried:

```
# echo '7' > /sys/class/net/eno1/device/sriov_numvfs
bash: /sys/class/net/eno1/device/sriov_numvfs: Permission denied
```

Is the configuration correct?

### Update:

After updating the ixgbe driver to the last one I get:

```
$ dmesg | grep iov
[    3.834884] ixgbe 0000:19:00.0: echo '32' > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:19:00.0/sriov_numvfs
[    3.834894] ixgbe 0000:19:00.0 0000:19:00.0 (uninitialized): Failed to enable PCI sriov: -38
```

Many thanks.
Gabriele

Comment: Are the usual IOMMU/DMAR messages showing up - compare your system after boot to [this Questions output]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286683/check-for-iommu-support-on-linux). In general posting (as pastebin or such) a full dmesg is often useful for IOMMU setup related questions.

Comment: Thank @ChristianEhrhardt here the [output of dmesg | grep iommu ](https://pastebin.com/byLHq77w) to me seems that IOMMU is enabled and I can also see the PCI address of the network cards ( 0000:19:00.0 to 0000:1a:00.1)
I also posy the [full dmesg](https://pastebin.com/uV2jeq8v) if you think that could help.

Also I need to configure it using sysfs instead of the parameter to the module?
[  378.661692] ixgbe 0000:19:00.1: Enabling SR-IOV VFs using the max_vfs module parameter is deprecated - please use the pci sysfs interface instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this, was a lack of documentation from Dell side.
I had to enable also SR-IOV for each NIC, in the Device Settigs from the System Configuration, the global enabler is not enough.